# Twitter List API (PHP)

Tags: php, twitter

I've recently used a php version of the twitter search API to display tweets on my website.

Now I'm looking to use an API to show tweets from a list I have created on twitter, but I can't seem to find any resources or examples.

Answer (score 2):

Using List Widgets is an alternative. No need to write any PHP code. By overriding the CSS styles you can integrate the widget into your website theme.

http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_list

Answer (score 1):

PEAR has a nice twitter API package; http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Twitter/ - that's probably easier than writing your own adapter.